# How To Parse Scripts With Beautiful Soup?

Tags: django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to parse some data within the script tag. First challenge is that there are several script tags on the page with no ids or classes. The one I need looks like this:

```
<script>
    window.runParams = {
        data: {
            "priceModule":{
                "maxActivityAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $28.71",
                    "value":28.71 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "maxAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $52.20",
                    "value":52.2 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "minActivityAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $6.83",
                    "value":6.83 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED***
                },
                "minAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $12.42",
                    "value":12.42 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED***
                },
            },
            "freightItemModule":{
                "commitDay":"60",
                "company":"Standard Shipping",
                "currency":"USD",
                "discount":100,
                "displayType":"deliveryTime",
                "features":{
                },
                "freightAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $0.00",
                    "value":0.0 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "fullMailLine":false,
                "hbaService":false,
                "i18nMap":{
                },
                "id":0,
                "name":"FreightItemModule",
                "notification":"",
                "sendGoodsCountry":"CN",
                "sendGoodsCountryFullName":"China",
                "serviceName":"CAINIAO_STANDARD",
                "standardFreightAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $13.12",
                    "value":13.12 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "time":"17-25",
                "tracking":true
            },
            "skuModule":{
                "categoryId":200001392,
                "features":{
                },"
                forcePromiseWarrantyJson":"{
                }",
                "hasSizeInfo":false,
                "hasSkuProperty":true,
                "id":0,
                "name":"SKUModule",
                "productSKUPropertyList":[{
                    "isShowTypeColor":false,
                    "order":1,
                    "showType":"none",
                    "showTypeColor":false,
                    "skuPropertyId":14,
                    "skuPropertyName":"????",
                    "skuActivityAmount":{
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "formatedAmount":"US $12.38",
                        "value":12.38 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                    },
                    "skuAmount":{
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "formatedAmount":"US $22.51",
                        "value":22.51 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice":"22.51",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"22.51",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"22.51"
                }
            },
        },
    };

    var GaData = {
        pageType: "product",
        productIds: "32955439786",
        totalValue: "US $6.83"
    };

    var PAGE_TIMING = {
        pageType: 'gloDetail'
    };
</script>
```

I need to parse `[value]` within the `[data]` -> `[priceModule]` -> `[minActivityAmount]` & `[minAmount]` and save them under two separate variables: `activity_amount = 6.83` and `amount = 12.42`. As you can see there are multiple "values" within multiple "modules". So parsing them using regex doesn't seem ideal. Maybe there is a better way how to extract these values from the this script? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: I'm sorry, it's python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `BeautifulSoup` doesn't provide a tool to extract the JS content.

A way to solve this is using regex

```py
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<script>
    window.runParams = {
        data: {
            "priceModule":{
                "maxActivityAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $28.71",
                    "value":28.71 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "maxAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $52.20",
                    "value":52.2 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "minActivityAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $6.83",
                    "value":6.83 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED***
                },
                "minAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $12.42",
                    "value":12.42 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED***
                },
            },
            "freightItemModule":{
                "commitDay":"60",
                "company":"Standard Shipping",
                "currency":"USD",
                "discount":100,
                "displayType":"deliveryTime",
                "features":{
                },
                "freightAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $0.00",
                    "value":0.0 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "fullMailLine":false,
                "hbaService":false,
                "i18nMap":{
                },
                "id":0,
                "name":"FreightItemModule",
                "notification":"",
                "sendGoodsCountry":"CN",
                "sendGoodsCountryFullName":"China",
                "serviceName":"CAINIAO_STANDARD",
                "standardFreightAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $13.12",
                    "value":13.12 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "time":"17-25",
                "tracking":true
            },
            "skuModule":{
                "categoryId":200001392,
                "features":{
                },"
                forcePromiseWarrantyJson":"{
                }",
                "hasSizeInfo":false,
                "hasSkuProperty":true,
                "id":0,
                "name":"SKUModule",
                "productSKUPropertyList":[{
                    "isShowTypeColor":false,
                    "order":1,
                    "showType":"none",
                    "showTypeColor":false,
                    "skuPropertyId":14,
                    "skuPropertyName":"????",
                    "skuActivityAmount":{
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "formatedAmount":"US $12.38",
                        "value":12.38 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                    },
                    "skuAmount":{
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "formatedAmount":"US $22.51",
                        "value":22.51 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice":"22.51",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"22.51",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"22.51"
                }
            },
        },
    };

    var GaData = {
        pageType: "product",
        productIds: "32955439786",
        totalValue: "US $6.83"
    };

    var PAGE_TIMING = {
        pageType: 'gloDetail'
    };
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, features='html.parser')
script = soup.find('script')

values = []
keys = ['minActivityAmount', 'minAmount']
for key in keys:
    value = re.search(r'(?<=\"%s\":{)([^]]+?)(?=\})' % key, script.text)
    value = re.search(r'(?<="value":)([0-9.,]+)', value.group())
    values.append(value.group())

print(values)
```

Output:

```
['6.83', '12.42']
```

Comment: Thank you! But this is not ideal, as there are multiple values and I want to separate them. Is there any other way how to do this?

Comment: @Android_Minsky - What do you mean by "there are multiple values and I want to separate them"?

Comment: @Jack Fleeting - I've provided just a small part of the script. It has several "modules" (i.e. "productModule", "titleModule", etc.) with lots of "values" within them. This way I will get a long list of values, but I need just a two of them saved under two different variables.

Comment: @Android_Minsky - Maybe the way to handle it (if at all possible) is for you to post one of those "modules" containing 4-5 "values" and then changing the text of some of these "values" from (using your code example) "6.83" to "6.83 - wanted" and of the others to "x.xx - not wanted/discard" - just to clarify which ones are your targets.

Comment: @Jack Fleeting - I've edited my initial post. Hopefully my question is a bit clearer now. Thanks!

Comment: I did an edit to capture only specific values as you wish, take a look

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it without regex (and without BeautifulSoup, for that matter); it's somewhat convoluted, but it should work. It basically splits the script into smaller chunks until the each target data is segregated in its own chunk, and then extracts the target from the chunk.

```
data = [your script above]

items = ' '.join(data.split()).split('}, "')

for item in items:
if ("minAmount" in item or "minActivityAmount" in item):        
    print(item.split('"value":')[1].replace('},',''))
```

Output:

```
 6.83 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED*** 
12.42 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED***
```

Answer (score 1):

Another regex

```
import re

html = '''
<script>
    window.runParams = {
        data: {
            "priceModule":{
                "maxActivityAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $28.71",
                    "value":28.71 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "maxAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $52.20",
                    "value":52.2 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "minActivityAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $6.83",
                    "value":6.83 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED***
                },
                "minAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $12.42",
                    "value":12.42 ***THIS IS THE VALUE I NEED***
                },
            },
            "freightItemModule":{
                "commitDay":"60",
                "company":"Standard Shipping",
                "currency":"USD",
                "discount":100,
                "displayType":"deliveryTime",
                "features":{
                },
                "freightAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $0.00",
                    "value":0.0 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "fullMailLine":false,
                "hbaService":false,
                "i18nMap":{
                },
                "id":0,
                "name":"FreightItemModule",
                "notification":"",
                "sendGoodsCountry":"CN",
                "sendGoodsCountryFullName":"China",
                "serviceName":"CAINIAO_STANDARD",
                "standardFreightAmount":{
                    "currency":"USD",
                    "formatedAmount":"US $13.12",
                    "value":13.12 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                },
                "time":"17-25",
                "tracking":true
            },
            "skuModule":{
                "categoryId":200001392,
                "features":{
                },"
                forcePromiseWarrantyJson":"{
                }",
                "hasSizeInfo":false,
                "hasSkuProperty":true,
                "id":0,
                "name":"SKUModule",
                "productSKUPropertyList":[{
                    "isShowTypeColor":false,
                    "order":1,
                    "showType":"none",
                    "showTypeColor":false,
                    "skuPropertyId":14,
                    "skuPropertyName":"????",
                    "skuActivityAmount":{
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "formatedAmount":"US $12.38",
                        "value":12.38 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                    },
                    "skuAmount":{
                        "currency":"USD",
                        "formatedAmount":"US $22.51",
                        "value":22.51 ***VALUE TO IGNORE***
                    },
                    "skuCalPrice":"22.51",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyCalPrice":"22.51",
                    "skuMultiCurrencyDisplayPrice":"22.51"
                }
            },
        },
    };

    var GaData = {
        pageType: "product",
        productIds: "32955439786",
        totalValue: "US $6.83"
    };

    var PAGE_TIMING = {
        pageType: 'gloDetail'
    };
</script>
'''
p1 = re.compile(r'"minActivityAmount":(.*?),[\n\t\s]+"freightItemModule"', re.DOTALL)
text = p1.findall(html)[0]
p2 = re.compile(r'value":\d+\.?\d+')
results = p2.findall(text)
print(results)
```